# Detect if an circle is clicked in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a class of Circle
It is:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, circle_x, cirlce_y, circle_radius):
        self.circle_x = circle_x
        self.circle_y = cirlce_y
        self.circle_radius = circle_radius

    def clicked(self):
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        area = math.pi * self.circle_radius * self.circle_radius
        print(area)
        if self.circle_x - self.circle_radius <= mouse_x <= self.circle_x + self.circle_radius and self.circle_y -  self.circle_radius <= mouse_y <= self.circle_y + self.circle_radius:
            return True
```

the problem is that it is working good but when as the circle have round edges. But wheni click on the a point some distance away from the edge of the circle its still detecting that the circle is clicked.
how can i omit this error and detect circle click only in the circle boundary not detecting circle as a sqaure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the center of the circle and the mouse. Test if this distance is less than the radius:

```py
def clicked(self):
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dx = mouse_x - self.circle_x
    dy = mouse_y - self.circle_y
    distance = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)  # or: distance = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    return distance <= self.circle_radius
```

You can improve performance and get rid of the costly `math.sqrt` operation by comparing the square of the distance to the square of the radius:

```py
def clicked(self):
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    dx = mouse_x - self.circle_x
    dy = mouse_y - self.circle_y
    return dx*dx + dy*dy <= self.circle_radius*self.circle_radius
```

Comment: you could compare the distance without using the expensive `math.sqrt` if you just compare it to `radius * radius`.

Comment: @KYL3R Yes I know. In any case, I have included this option in the answer.